# Match text to encoded link text (XSLT)

Tags: xslt

I am attempting to process a document that has a url that is xml-encoded and is an attribute of the current node. I want to match the contents of the  tag with a static string. The best I can do so far is using contains:

```
<xsl:when test="contains(@Activity,'&gt;stringToMatch&lt;/a&gt;')" >
```

Is there a better way?